# What is the name of new feature testing in maintenance process?

Tags: manual-testing

In the software maintenance process, after a new version is built, there comes software maintenance testing.

In extent of software maintenance testing, it is done;

- Confirmation Testing, for fixed defects
- X testing, for new features
- Y testing, for modifications of existing features
- Regression Testing, to ensure that the changes not introduced new defects.

Please fill in the blanks, what is X and Y Testing?

Comment: I would argue you should /never/ attempt to confirm defects are fixed because its too easy to fall into a confirmation bias and miss important problems. Instead you should try to prove the fixed defects were not fixed and if you can't then state so.

Comment: Chris, you are right. However, what you described should be the common viewpoint of testers. Every test case (scripted or in head) is a chance to break the system for a tester. Trying to prove "the defect is fixed" is more likely a developer's approach. :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

For new features and changes to existing features, exactly how you label the testing that's done will depend on a number of factors, including:

- how much the feature or change affects other parts of the system
- whether the new build is a release candidate or not
- whether the feature or change is still in active development
- whether the development process is agile or not (yes, this does make a difference in my experience)

In my experience, it usually all get labeled in the catch-all of "functional testing" and precisely how much and how detailed depends on the change and where in the process the new build is made available.

Comment: Thanks Kate. I want to know the name of this testing type in SQA literature. Assume that, the size of change is small, development for a couple of CR records. Coders finished the development and I have a build in testing machine. And not agile. I have came across the term in a website related to software testing last weeks, but forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to agree with Kate that it depends. Personally I haven't seen a "standard or common term" in testing literature that **only describes** changes to new functionality or to existing functionality.

The industry tends to give formal labels or terms to **test techniques** and **approaches** based on what we are trying to discover or measure. So a term like regression testing might be considered an activity based technique, functional testing might be considered a coverage based technique, etc. It seems like the items you've listed you are worried about risks based tests (finding potential problems) associated with new features, changes to existing features, etc.

If you are concerned about sounding credible when referring to these things, my advice is: *be simple and direct*. For example I might say:

- I'm testing bug fixes (or trying to disprove bug fixes)
- I'm testing new features
- I'm testing changes to existing features
- I'm regression testing x, y, z features

It doesn't matter so much what label you use, as long as your team and the people you work with understand what you are doing and/or trust you to do the job.

Comment: Chris, thank you for your answer. Talking from the literature makes people more credible. And shows better that you know what you are doing. I was curious about this testing type if there is a name in literature. And I agree with you about your advice on being simple.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily they can be

X --> Sanity Testing

Y --> Regression Testing

There can be other values also for Y such as Integration testing or System testing

Comment: Hi ashu, thank you for your answer. Actually my point is in a simple way, what is the name of the test type which only tests the new features. You are right, it can be done all test levels such integration and system testing according to the size of change. I saw in a testing blog and forgot the name of it. I couldn't find it again and any answer for this in google.

Comment: Sanity testing can also be called smoke testing and is generally done with new features but can also be done with old features that /you/ (as a tester) are new to.

Comment: Sanity testing is actually a subset of user acceptance test and not covers all new features. Scope of Smoke Testing is complete system and the scope of Sanity Testing is specific component(s).